# Understanding exception handling in with statement in python

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the with statement in python but I don't get how it does exception handling.

For example, we have this code

```
file = open('file-path', 'w') 
try: 
    file.write('Lorem ipsum') 
finally: 
    file.close()
```

and then this code

```
with open('file_path', 'w') as file:
    file.write('hello world !')
```

Here when is `file.close()` is called? From this question I think because python have `entry` and `exit` function (and exit function is called by itself when file.write(); is over?) but then how are we going to do exception handling (`catch`) statement in particular?

Also, what if we don't write `finally` in first snippet, it won't close connection by itself?

```
file = open('file-path', 'w') 
try: 
    file.write('Lorem ipsum')
```

Comment: Not sure what exception handling has to do with this. The `with` block executes an exit function *at the end of the block*. In the case of a file handler, the exit function closes the file. No exception happening here. What you do with `try..finally` is simply ensure that `file.close` will always be called, even if an exception should happen in `file.write`. A `with` block as the same effect.

Comment: A `try` without an `except` or `finally` block is a syntax error BTW…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `with` statements, `__exit__` will be called whenever we leave the `with` block, regardless of if we leave it due to exception or if we just finished executing contained code normally.

If any code contained in the with block causes an exception, it will cause the `__exit__` to run and then propagate the exception to the surrounding try/except block.

This snippet (added `finally: pass` for the sake of syntax correctness):

```
file = open('file-path', 'w') 
try: 
    file.write('Lorem ipsum')
finally:
    pass
```

will never cause the file to be closed, so it will remain open for the whole run of the program (assuming close is not called anywhere else).